# Problems playing sound with TMediaPlayer on Android

Tags: android, firemonkey, c++builder

To reproduce my problem in the simplest way: I create a form that contains a button, and clicking it generates a thread where a sound is played in a loop.

```
void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TRecitar *Recitar = new TRecitar(false);
}
```

```
class TRecitar : public TThread
{
private:
    UnicodeString  PathGhost;
    
protected:
    void __fastcall Execute();
public:
    
    __fastcall TRecitar(bool CreateSuspended);
    
};
    
    
__fastcall TRecitar::TRecitar(bool CreateSuspended)
    : TThread(CreateSuspended)
{
    PathGhost=System::Ioutils::TPath::GetDocumentsPath()+"/";
}
        
void __fastcall TRecitar::Execute()
{
    FreeOnTerminate = true;
    
    AnsiString Audio;
    
    TMediaPlayer *Pl;
    
    for(int i=1;i<150;i++)
    {
        Audio = PathGhost + "Multimedia/SonG.3gp";

        Pl->FileName = Audio;
        Pl->Play();
        sleep(1);
        Pl->Stop();
        Pl->Clear();
    }
}
```

When starting the process, the sound is played in a loop up to a certain number of times (in my case 40), and then it stops being "heard", but the loop continues running without giving any type of error (it simply does not reproduce the sound).

I've tried a thousand things but I can't find the error... it could be a problem on my android... ... Any ideas?

Comment: First off, you are dereferencing an *uninitialized pointer*, as you are not creating the `TMediaPlayer` object before accessing it. Second, I'm not sure if `TMediaPlayer` even works in a thread without `Synchronize`'ing with the main UI thread. Third, why are you using `AnsiString`? The `FileName` is a `UnicodeString`.

Comment: Garacias por contestar.. para inicializar el puntero TMediaPlayer habia probado con  ```new TMediaPlayer ()``` y  ```new TMediaPlayer (this)```.. ninguna de las dos es compatible con el componente TMediaPlayer... creo que se inicializa al asignarle un Nombre.

Comment: No, you must `new` the `TMediaPlayer` object before you can do anything with it. Your attempts didn't work because 1) `TMediaPlayer` does not have a default constructor, and 2) `this` is pointing at the `TThread` object, which is not derived from `TComponent`. You can use `new TMediaPlayer(nullptr)` in this case. Just make sure to `delete` it when you are done using it. Consider using `std::unique_ptr` to manage that for you